# What is the purpose of sockets in layman terms?

Tags: socket

I met several times the term "socket", so I looked it up on different
sites, but each of them required too much knowledge in order to
understand the explanation.

What I read were things like:

- sockets fall into the same category as pipes and name pipes
- sockets offer some kind of two-way communication
- sockets are used in inter-process communication
- sockets are sometimes mentioned with regard to networks

I do not really get the big picture, what is the very purpose of a socket. Could you explain it maybe in terms that would not require too much technical knowledge (like C language)?